TypeScript util type challenge: snake_case to camelCase and vice versa
I want to create a function in Typescript that traverses deeply a Plain object and replaces all snake_case keys with camelCase. Also I want to create a function that converts camelCase keys to snake_case deeply.
Implementing this in JavaScript is easy, but it's hard for me because I have to consider types.
How do I write this in TypeScript?
My JS version:
const keyToSnakeCase = obj => {
    if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
        return obj.map(el => keyToSnakeCase(el));
    }

    if (!isPlainObject(obj)) {
        return obj;
    }

    const newObj = {};

    Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
        newObj[camelCase(key)] = keyToSnakeCase(value);
    });

    return newObj;
};

const keyToCamelCase = obj => {
    if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
        return obj.map(el => keyToCamelCase(el));
    }

    if (!isPlainObject(obj)) {
        return obj;
    }

    const newObj = {};

    Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
        newObj[snakeCase(key)] = keyToCamelCase(value);
    });

    return newObj;
};


So your issue here is that the input object can be of any type?
My guess is that this is what you are looking for. Or you can use "any" as a type, but then there is no real point of using typescript.

@Tony What if the argument is object type?

What do you mean?
Actually I think in your case there is indeed no need to use generic type. You can just do it like this for function defenitions:
const keyToSnakeCase = (obj: any): any => {
And like this for the loops:
Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]: [string, any]) => {
unless your project has restrictions on any.

Please provide a [mre] along with a suite of test cases you care about. I presume you're not asking about the implementation, but if you are providing code you should provide all of it that's needed for your example to be demonstrable. My IDE doesn't know what isPlainObject, snakeCase, or camelCase are. I can guess that maybe this playground link is what you're asking for, but without test use cases it's just a guess. Please [edit] to give a true [mre] with criteria for success, and let me know if an answer along the lines of my playground link would suffice here.

@jcalz Thanks I solved it thanks to you. I'll leave an answer with my solution.

It would be most appreciated if, instead of posting your own answer without explanation for how it works, you would [edit] your question as I asked so that future readers will benefit, and then I'll post an answer with an explanation.

@jcalz Okay I'll edit my question and remove my answer

Thanks to @jcalz, I solved the problem.
import isPlainObject from "lodash-es/isPlainObject";
import camelCase from "lodash-es/camelCase";
import snakeCase from "lodash-es/snakeCase";

type SnakeToCamel<T extends string> = T extends `${infer F}_${infer R}`
  ? `${Lowercase<F>}${Capitalize<SnakeToCamel<R>>}`
  : T;

type CamelToSnake<
  T extends string,
  A extends string = ""
> = T extends `${infer F}${infer R}`
  ? CamelToSnake<R, `${A}${F extends Lowercase<F> ? F : `_${Lowercase<F>}`}`>
  : A;

type DeepCamelKeys<T> = T extends readonly any[]
  ? { [I in keyof T]: DeepCamelKeys<T[I]> }
  : T extends object
  ? {
      [K in keyof T as K extends string ? SnakeToCamel<K> : K]: DeepCamelKeys<
        T[K]
      >;
    }
  : T;

type DeepSnakeKeys<T> = T extends readonly any[]
  ? { [I in keyof T]: DeepSnakeKeys<T[I]> }
  : T extends object
  ? {
      [K in keyof T as K extends string ? CamelToSnake<K> : K]: DeepSnakeKeys<
        T[K]
      >;
    }
  : T;

function keyToSnakeCase<T>(obj: T): DeepSnakeKeys<T>;
function keyToSnakeCase(obj: any) {
  if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
    return obj.map((el) => keyToSnakeCase(el));
  }

  if (!isPlainObject(obj)) {
    return obj;
  }

  const newObj: any = {};

  Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    newObj[camelCase(key)] = keyToSnakeCase(value);
  });

  return newObj;
}

function keyToCamelCase<T>(obj: T): DeepCamelKeys<T>;
function keyToCamelCase(obj: any) {
  if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
    return obj.map((el) => keyToCamelCase(el));
  }

  if (!isPlainObject(obj)) {
    return obj;
  }

  const newObj: any = {};

  Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    newObj[snakeCase(key)] = keyToCamelCase(value);
  });

  return newObj;
}


@jcalz Sorry I edited. What do you mean 'How does it work'?

I am asking for you to provide an explanation for how your code works. This is a code-only answer.
